# Liferay 7.4 extend session returning internal server error from Liferay until fetch

Tags: liferay, fetch-api, liferay-dxp

In Liferay 7.4 session.js Liferay.util.fetch(“/c/portal/extend_session”) retuning 500 status and “internal server error” in browser console. In server log “unable to extend session” warning is throwing.
Because of this user becoming in active and getting logged out.

Thanks…

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and provide a [mcve].